# HTTP GET API Design which uses same endpoint but with provides filtered results with request parameters in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restplus

I am using `flask-restplus` to create a RESTful API which connects to a MongoDB collection and provides information according to the API called.

### API Design

**HTTP GET**

```
api/hashdoc/<str:product_id>
```

*function*: provides all a `list` of the relevant information for the given `product_id` in the Database.

*example response*:

```
[
  {
    "product_id": "ABC",
    "metadata": {
        ...
    },
    "time_info": {
       ....
    }
  },
  {
    "product_id": "ABC",
    "metadata": {
       ...
    },
    "time_info": {
        ...
     }
  }
]
```

---

**HTTP GET**

```
api/hashdoc/<str:product_id>?from=<str:ISO8601_timestamp>&to=<str:ISO8601_timestamp>
```

*function*: **Should** Provide a JSON response of information filtered using `from` and `to` values in the Database

*example response*:

```
   {
    "product_id": "ABC",
    "metadata": {
     ...
    },
    "time_info": {
        ...
    }
   }
```

### Current Implementation

Within my `hashdoc.py` I have the following code:

```py
from flask import request, abort
from flask_restplus import Namespace, Resource, fields, reqparse
from databases.documentdb import mongo

# API
api = Namespace('hashdoc', description='Hash Document Operations')


# REQUEST PARSER HERE
event_duration_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()

event_duration_parser.add_argument('from', type=str, required=True, help='ISO8601 UTC Timestamp (ms precision)')
event_duration_parser.add_argument('to', type=str, required=True, help='ISO8601 UTC Timestamp (ms precision)')

## hash_doc = api.model(....) removed for brewity

@api.route('/<product_id>')
@api.param('product_id', 'EPC Product ID')
@api.response(404, 'No Values Exist for given Product ID.')
class HashDocListResource(Resource):
    @api.marshal_list_with(hash_doc)
    def get(self, product_id):
        '''Fetch Hash Documents for given Product ID'''
        print(product_id)
        product_hash_doc = mongo.db['HashData'].find({'product_id': product_id}, {'_id': 0})
        list_product_hashdoc = list(product_hash_doc)
        if len(list_product_hashdoc):
            return list_product_hashdoc, 200
        else:
            abort(404, {'error': 'No Values Exist for given Product ID.'})


@api.route('/<product_id>')
@api.param('product_id', 'EPC Product ID')
@api.response(404, 'No Values Exist for given Product ID & Time Range')
class HashDocResource(Resource):
    @api.expect(event_duration_parser)
    @api.marshal_with(hash_doc)
    def get(self, product_id):
        args = event_duration_parser.parse_args()
        from_time = args.get('from')
        to_time = args.get('to')

        product_hash_doc_for_time_range = mongo.db['HashData'].find_one(
                        {'product_id': product_id, 
                         # Filtering based on TIMESTAMPS HERE
                        {'_id': 0})

        if product_hash_doc_for_time_range:
            return product_hash_doc_for_time_range, 200
        else:
            abort(404, 'No Values Exist for given Product ID & Time Range')
```

### Tests

with `curl` I perform the following:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:5000/api/hashdoc/ABC
```

which provides me the `list` of the hash documents and the behaviour is correct. However when I do the following:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:5000/api/hashdoc/ABC?from\="2019-11-05T14:32:31.830000Z"\&to\="2019-11-05T14:46:00.444000Z"
```

The Flask app still queries the `api/hashdoc/ABC` and provides me the list and not the filtered document here.

How does one manage such API with request parameters? Does one need to implement them separately?

Does one have to perform a check if the `from` and `to` are not `None` in the same resource class and then perform the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Flask app still queries the api/hashdoc/ABC and provides me the
>   list and not the filtered document here.

You created two resource classes with same route url. So it uses the one it sees first (which in your case is the `HashDocListResource`).

> How does one manage such API with request parameters? Does one need to
>   implement them separately?

No, you don't make separate resource classes just for query params.

> Does one have to perform a check if the from and to are not None in
>   the same resource class and then perform the query?

Yes.

I am not sure why you are using `find` in `HashDocListResource` but `find_one` in `HashDocResource`. Is it that there can only be one HashDoc in given time range?

Sample implementation of the same.

```py
from flask import request, abort
from flask_restplus import Namespace, Resource, fields, reqparse
from databases.documentdb import mongo

# API
api = Namespace('hashdoc', description='Hash Document Operations')


# REQUEST PARSER HERE
event_duration_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()

event_duration_parser.add_argument('from', type=str, required=True, help='ISO8601 UTC Timestamp (ms precision)')
event_duration_parser.add_argument('to', type=str, required=True, help='ISO8601 UTC Timestamp (ms precision)')

## hash_doc = api.model(....) removed for brewity

@api.route('/<product_id>')
@api.param('product_id', 'EPC Product ID')
@api.response(404, 'No Values Exist for given Product ID.')
class HashDocListResource(Resource):
    @api.expect(event_duration_parser)
    @api.marshal_list_with(hash_doc)
    def get(self, product_id):
        '''Fetch Hash Documents for given Product ID'''
        args = event_duration_parser.parse_args()
        from_time = args.get('from')
        to_time = args.get('to')

        query = {
            'product_id': product_id,
        }
        if from_time and to_time:
            query['your_time_stamp_field'] = {
                '$lte': to_time
            }
            query['your_time_stamp_field'] = {
                '$gte': from_time
            }
        projection = {'_id': 0}
        product_hash_docs = mongo.db['HashData'].find(query, projection)
        list_product_hashdoc = list(product_hash_docs)
        if len(list_product_hashdoc):
            return list_product_hashdoc, 200
        else:
            abort(404, {'error': 'No Values Exist for given Product ID.'})
```

Comment: yes I have an automated script that stores the timestamps for particular product and it is unique. So when one queries with a particular timestamp there is exactly one document available in the collection.

Comment: Is it possible to send a list if there is no request parameters and single document if there is one? @SrikanthChekuri

Comment: Your API behavior has to consistent irrespective of query params. What I meant by that is you send list even if there is one doc so client doesn't have to have two different piece of code for processing data from same api endpoint.